# JQuery looping data

Tags: jquery

i have something like this:

```
 $("#btn").click(function (event) {
                $.getJSON(url,
                function (data) {
                    // i using this which works fine... 
                    //alert(data[0].Id);
                    //alert(data[0].Name);
                    //alert(data[0].Tion);
                    //alert(data[0].Path);
                    //alert(data[0].Flag);

                    //how do i loop here 
                    $(data).each(function() {
                        alert(data);
                    });

                });
            });
```

Comment: is it giving you an error or something? whats the problem?

Comment: Putting your question in the comments is cute but also very counter intuitive. It would be better if you ask your question explicitly outside the code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$.each(data, function(idx, dataItem) {
    alert(dataItem.Id);
    alert(dataItem.Name);
    alert(dataItem.Tion);
    alert(dataItem.Path);
    alert(dataItem.Flag);
});
```

Or, a more terse version, in which `this` is automatically assigned to each element in `data` for you:

```
$.each(data, function() {
    alert(this.Id);
    alert(this.Name);
    alert(this.Tion);
    alert(this.Path);
    alert(this.Flag);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
       $("#btn").click(function (event) {
            $.getJSON(url,
            function (data) {

                $(data).each(function(index, dataR) {
                   alert(dataR.Id);
                   alert(dataR.Name);
                   alert(dataR.Tion);
                   alert(dataR.Path);
                   alert(dataR.Flag);
                });

            });
        });
```

Comment: +1 I didn't think it would work to send an Array of non-DOM elements to the prototyped `.each()`, but it seems that it does.

Comment: @patrickdw -- it does not have to be. see source: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.1&fn=jQuery.each

Comment: @Neal: Then you meant `$.each(data,function(){...})`

Comment: @Neal: Then I'm totally confused about what you mean. If `data` was rendered from JSON Array notation, then we have a JavaScript Array, which doesn't have an `.each()` method, so `data.each` is `undefined`, so `data.each(function(){})` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`jQuery.each()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method instead of the [`each()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method in order to enumerate collections that are not jQuery objects.

```
$.each(data,function() {
    alert(this);
});
```

...or if your collection is coming from a JSON Object, can use `for/in` statement.

```
for( var key in data ) {
    alert( data[key] );
}
```

...or for a JSON Array, use a `for` statement.

```
for( var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    alert( data[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normal `for` loop.

If you really want to use jQuery, you need to call the static version:

```
$.each(data, function(index) { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$.each(data, function(){
   alert(data);
});
```

Comment: Hooo seems like patrick dw already posted this a second before me ;)

Answer (score 0):

The [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function accepts arguments, the collection to iterate, and a function. The function specified can further have an iterative index passed along with a value.

For your purposes, something like this ought to help out:

```
$.each(data, function() {
    alert(this);
});
```